# Insert PHP variable in external link

Tags: php, href

The link works perfectly fine internally on the domain, just won't work for an external website. Didn't see anything in the documentation. I provided an example below. Would appreciate some insight.

```
<?php $user = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>

<a href="https://www.externaldomain.com/secure/cart/addItem.aspx?qty=1&itID=9135&PromoID=83&uid=<?php echo $user->username ?>">
```

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't work" ? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: It doesn't include the variable. The link forwards without including $user.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($user)` after the first line?

Comment: `basename()` returns a `string`... it is not supposed to contain `$user->username`

Comment: I was trying to use the string ID to include that in the external link. Is there another way to handle that? The page string ID is the same as the ending part of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you comment, you must have a page url like `page.php?ID=userid` and you want something like this: `{externalpage.com/page.php}?uid=userid`

Try:

```
<a href="https://www.externaldomain.com/secure/cart/addItem.aspx?qty=1&itID=9135&PromoID=83&uid=<?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>">
```

## Edit

Based on your last comment, try this:

```
<?php $user = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>
<a href="https://www.externaldomain.com/secure/cart/addItem.aspx?qty=1&itID=9135&PromoID=83&uid=<?php echo $user; ?>">
```

Comment: Yeah, it returns the same thing. Sorry, I'll try to explain it better. Example. www.domain.com/sample with "sample" being the ID. The external link www.externaldomain.com/sample

Comment: It returns www.externaldomain.com/index.php it won't pass the $user variable. The page ID is always a generic name like /Joshua.